# Single clause with if-the-else vs multiple clause predicates

Tags: performance, prolog

Let's say I want to implement a predicate that 'returns' a list of all elements shared by a list of lists.

I can implement it as a one clause (looks bit ugly for logic programing):

```
shared_members(Members, Lists) :-
    Lists = [] -> 
      Members = []
    ; findall(M, (maplist(member(M), Lists)), Members).
```

or as a set of clauses:

```
shared_members([], []). % possibly adding cut here to increase effciency

shared_members(Members, Lists) :-
    findall(M, (maplist(member(M), Lists)), Members).
```

Which implementation is considered to be more efficient?
I know it depends on the Prolog implementation but maybe there is a general stand about efficiency of these cases.

Comment: In this case, you don't even need the first clause `shared_member([], [])`. The `findall/3` call will result in `Members = []` if `Lists = []`.

Comment: If you are really concerned about performance, get rid of findall and member!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you don't even need the first clause `shared_member([], [])`. The `findall/3` call will result in `Members = []` if `Lists = []`.

The question is still interesting, though, and so we'll ignore this for now. You could run some stats to determine time-efficiency. Memory efficiency difference is negligible. The second approach given, however, is considered to be the canonical approach in Prolog. But they are also not equivalent in their behavior. The "if-else" in Prolog, as represented by `p1 -> p2 ; p3` cuts removes the choice point after evaluation of `p1`. It's equivalent to `p1, !, p2 ; p3`.

Here's why this matters. I'll use a contrived example (which also does not require both clauses, but illustrates the point). I'll define a `len/2` predicate that is true if the first argument is the length of the second:

```
len(0, []).
len(N, L) :- length(L, N).
```

Obviously, as in the case of the original problem, the first clause here is redundant, but it is important for this illustration. If I run this query, I get the following results:

```
| ?- len(N, [a,b,c]).

N = 3

yes
| ?- len(3, L).

L = [_,_,_]

yes
| ?- len(N, L).

L = []
N = 0 ? ;

L = []
N = 0 ? ;

L = [_]
N = 1 ? ;

L = [_,_]
N = 2 ? ;

L = [_,_,_]
N = 3 ?
```

Note that if both arguments are variable, it enumerates solutions. (Also, due to the redundant first clause, one of the solutions appears twice.)

Let's rewrite this predicate using "if-else":

```
len(N, L) :-
(   L = []
->  N = 0
;   length(L, N)
).
```

And we'll run it:

```
| ?- len(N, [a,b,c]).

N = 3

yes
```

So far, so good. But...

```
| ?- len(3, L).

no
| ?- len(N, L).

L = []
N = 0

yes
| ?-
```

Yikes! This is quite different. What happened?

In the second approach, `( L = [] -> N = 0 ; length(L, N) )` first attempts to unify `L` and `[]`. If `L` is a variable, this succeeds with `L = []`. Since it succeeded, Prolog then attempts to unify `N = 0`. But with the query `len(3, L)`, `N` is already bound to 3. So `N = 0` fails and the entire clause fails.

Using the `-> ;` construct then, in this case, greatly reduces the generality of the implementation and yields incorrect results in some of the call scenarios.